# Print several sentences with different colors

Tags: python, colorama

I'm trying to print several sentences with different colors, but it won't work, I only got 2 colors, the normal blue and this red

```
import sys
from colorama import init, AnsiToWin32

stream = AnsiToWin32(sys.stderr).stream

print(">>> This is red.", file=stream)
```

Comment: whats stopping you from importing `Fore` and doing `Fore.GREEN` etc.?

Comment: >>> import sys
>>> from colorama import init, Fore
>>> print(">>> This isn't green.", Fore.GREEN)
>>> This isn't green. [32m .
Like this?, Well this didn't work.

Comment: You have imported `init` but not actually used it. You need a `colorama.init()`

Comment: Look, I don't know much about Python, I'm just a beginner, so I have no idea what to do with colorama.init()  (I appreciate your help, but I'm not getting much further.) I have been searching everywhere for a code wich gives you several colors, but they always and up like this one.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, change your code to use these features;

```
import os, colorama
from colorama import Fore,Style,Back
colorama.init()

print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.BRIGHT + 'and in bright text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```

These are much easier to use and do job. The available colours you can use for `Fore` or `Back` are;

- Red
- Cyan
- Green
- Yellow
- Black
- Magenta
- Blue
- White

These will all be needed to be put in capitals.
And for `Style` you can use;

- Bright
- Dim
- Reset_all

These will also need to be in capitals.

Have fun using colorama :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it still does not work, maybe it's because I use python 3.4.2?

Comment: @lautje i use 3.4.4 so it shouldnt matter, are you running it in IDLE or the python intrepeter?

Comment: I run it in IDLE

Comment: Oh, that sucks, do you know how to change it/something that does work?

Comment: @lautje no, currently you cannot use any form of run time colour changes in IDLE only changing colours in the properties which isnt what you want, changing at run time can only be done in the interpreter

Comment: Then, I'll just wait till it works, and I'll just keep it on red and blue, But thanks

Comment: theres nothing wrong with the interpreter though? build your program in IDLE and then run it in the interpreter